# sudo deluser --remove-home root

Tags: users

When I type  sudo deluser --remove-home root it says that 'it may make the whole system unusable so stopping now without performing any action" and it doesn't work. Can you explain me why?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because removing the root user will make you system unusable. The system doesn't want to make himself dead so it aborts this self-destructive action. Why do you want to remove the root user?